# ActionSheet Won't Show in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiactionsheet

Ever since iOS 10.2.1 I have issues with UIActionSheets showing up in an iPad.  On iPhone they show just fine, but nothing ever happens on the iPad, using the same code.  I subclass the ActionSheet so I can have it BlockBased.  Here is the header:

```
@interface BlockBasedActionSheet : UIActionSheet<UIActionSheetDelegate> {
}

@property (copy) void (^cancelBlock)();
@property (copy) void (^downloadBlock)();
@property (copy) void (^streamBlock)();


- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle downloadButtonTitle:(NSString *)downloadButtonTitle streamButtonTitle:(NSString *)streamButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock downloadAction:(void (^)())downloadBlock streamAction:(void (^)())streamBlock;

@end
```

And the implementation file:

```
#import "BlockBasedActionSheet.h"
@implementation BlockBasedActionSheet
@synthesize cancelBlock = _cancelBlock, streamBlock = _streamBlock, downloadBlock = _downloadBlock;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle downloadButtonTitle:(NSString *)downloadButtonTitle streamButtonTitle:(NSString *)streamButtonTitle cancelAction:(void (^)())cancelBlock downloadAction:(void (^)())downloadBlock streamAction:(void (^)())streamBlock
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:downloadButtonTitle, streamButtonTitle, nil];
    if (self) {
        _cancelBlock = Block_copy(cancelBlock);
        _downloadBlock = Block_copy(downloadBlock);
        _streamBlock = Block_copy(streamBlock);
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSAssert(actionSheet == self, @"Wrong Action Sheet passed");
    if (buttonIndex == [self cancelButtonIndex]) {
        if (self.cancelBlock) {
            self.cancelBlock();
        }
    }
    if (buttonIndex == [self firstOtherButtonIndex]) {
        if (self.downloadBlock) {
            self.downloadBlock();
        }
    }
    if (buttonIndex == [self firstOtherButtonIndex] +1) {
        if (self.streamBlock) {
            self.streamBlock();
        }
    }

}

@end
```

I run it like this in the view controller that I need it in:

```
BlockBasedActionSheet *askSheet =
    [[BlockBasedActionSheet alloc] 
     initWithTitle:@"What Do You Want To Do" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" downloadButtonTitle:@"Download" streamButtonTitle:@"Stream" cancelAction:^ {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
     }downloadAction:^ {
}];
streamAction:^ {
}];
[askSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
    [askSheet release];
```

Why is it that this won't run in an iPad?

Comment: it's better to use UIAlertController, instead of UIActionSheet. 
UIActionSheet is deprecated.

   
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

Comment: The point is this used to work just fine, now it won't.  It is not a true UIActionSheet, it is subclassed because of how I need it to run.  The question isn't, "What should I use instead of this", @RatneshShukla, the question is, "Why is this not appearing"

Comment: *"Why is not appearing?"* Because you are using `UIActionSheet` instead of `UIAlertController` with its presentation controller properly setup for use on an iPad.

Comment: can you try  

- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated 
- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: Changed to `showInView:self.view` and it works fine.  Thanks for the help (NOT)...sometimes a solution can be reached that doesn't require a complete rewrite of 60 lines of code.